# c# opening pdf using console application

Tags: c#, pdf, console

I'm a newbie to c#. I would want to know how to open a pdf file using console application in a step by step manner.
What classes need to be imported and what references should be added.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. What would you like to do with the file ? View it ? Extract content ? Metadata ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at using [Process.Start Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Starts a process resource by specifying the name of a document or
>   application file and associates the resource with a new Process
>   component.

Also, maybe have a look at the overloaded methods [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if You are open it from your console application then simply write code

```
Process p=new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"G:\Test.pdf";
p.Start();
```

for That You have to use
using System.Diagnostics;

Answer (score 0):

[PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/) is a .NET library for processing PDF files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: got it! will know next time. love the site and community.